# Styling Card from react-native-elements: Align Title and icon vertically

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm using a Card from react-native-elements. Turns out I want to add an icon next to its title but I can't get it to look nice.
Here's my code:

```
<Card
  //title={this.props.item.offer.amount + " " + this.props.item.request.good}
  title={
    <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <View style={{display: "flex",flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 18, justifyContent: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{this.props.item.offer.amount + " " + this.props.item.request.good}</Text>
        <View style={{flexGrow: 1}} />
        <Button
        buttonStyle={styles.localize}
        icon={<Ionicons name="md-locate" color={'white'} size={28} style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}/>}
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.push('Rastrear')}
        />
      </View>
      <View
            style ={{
              borderWidth: 0.5,
              borderColor:'grey',
              margin:2,
        }}
      />
  </View>
  }
  titleStyle={{textAlign: 'left'}}
  containerStyle={{width: Dimensions.get('window').width-25}}>
  ...
</Card>
```

Turns out that looks like this:

[image]

What I want is to align the title and the icon vertically. How can I achieve this?

If comment out that "title" line you see inside of the Card and comment my personalized one it looks like this:

[image]

As you see the title here's centered vertically.

Update. styles.localize looks like this:

```
localize: {
    padding: 4,
    backgroundColor: '#FF5733',
    borderColor: '#FF5733',
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width-370, 
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

Comment: Try removing "flexDirection: "row" from style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, once you have already declared `justifyContent` to be `center` in the parent `View`, this would have effected the rest of the child `Views` to have this styling prop. What you can do is to replace `justifyContent` in the second `View` housing your `Text` and `Icon` components with `alignItems`. This should vertically align them in the space provided by your parent `View`.

Also, you can set a `height` constraint in the parent `View` and `textAlignVertical` in the `Text` for better alignment.

```
        <View style={{justifyContent: 'center', height: 60}}>
          <View style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{fontSize: 18, textAlignVertical: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>12 Mouses</Text>
            <View style={{flexGrow: 1}} />
            <Button
              buttonStyle={styles.localize}
              icon={<Icon name="md-locate" color={'white'} size={28} style={{alignSelf: 'center'}}/>}
              onPress={() => {}}
            />
          </View>
          <View
                style ={{
                  borderWidth: 0.5,
                  borderColor:'grey',
                  margin:2,
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

I have included a [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kenmistry/react-native-elements-card-1) here for testing. :)